# How to delete a qt environment in qtchooser

Tags: qt

You can add a new environment to qt chooser by running

```
qtchooser --install ENVNAME /path/to/qmake
```

But how do you **delete** an environment you no longer need?
According to the site below, you do not have such option.
How do you deal with that?

Thanks and sorry if it is obvious, I don't see the answer.

https://www.mankier.com/1/qtchooser